# Weil: Fibre Spaces in Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, fiber-bundles

I have spent a decent amount of time searching for the notes for Weil's *Fibre Spaces in Algebraic Geometry*, written by A. Wallace, both in print and online. Does anyone have a file of it they'd be generous enough to share?

Comment: Why don't you request it from a library? A few libraries near me have it. http://www.worldcat.org/title/fibre-spaces-in-algebraic-geometry/oclc/1161902